# Rails 7 dropdown page size items with Pagy gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagy

In my Rails 7 app I'm using Pagy gem for pagination. The pagination works well but now I want to give the user the ability to choose how many items they will see in the paginated list. According to the [docs](https://ddnexus.github.io/pagy/extras/items#gsc.tab=0) the implementation should be fairly easy:

```
# initializers/pagy.rb

require 'pagy/extras/items'

# Instance variables
Pagy::DEFAULT[:items]  = 10
Pagy::DEFAULT[:items_param] = :items
```

with sample controller:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @pagy, @payments = pagy_array(fetch_payments)
  end

  private

  def client
    @client ||= Test::Client.new
  end

  def fetch_payments
    client.payments.list(
      page: 1,
      per_page: 100,
      platform_id: current_user.platform_id,
    )
  end
end
```

But now I don't know how to create working dropdown (like this one) with paginated results inside the view.

Answer (score 0):

## in /config/initializers/pagy.rb

```
require 'pagy/extras/bootstrap'
PAGE_SIZES = [10, 15, 20, 25]
```

## in your /app/controllers/your_controller.rb

```
def index
    @pagy, @rooms = pagy(Room.all, items: params[:per_page] || "set_default")
end
```

## in your app/view

```
<% PAGE_SIZES.each do |size| %>
   <%= link_to size, url_for(per_page: size), class:"dropdown-item"%>
<% end %>
```